# How to access a list in a nested defaultdict python 2.7?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, defaultdict

I have the code below, which is able to give me the documents frequency for each `wordQ1`, now I need the term frequency `TF` of `wordQ1` (`TF` in each document `DocID`) and the `DocSize` of each `DocID`.

The data structure is like that:

```
FinalHash[wordQ1]={DocID: [TF,DocSize]}
```

My output should be like the following:

- The current document is 999
- The number of tokens contains in this document is 59
- george document frequency is 142 (I have this done)
- george term frequency in file 999 is 5

  ```
  Term_List1=[]
  DF1 = 0
  Term_List1 = FinalHash[wordQ1] # FinalHash is defaultdict
  for d in Term_List1: # is the list of all dictionaries where each dict contains {DocID: [TF,DocSize]}
      for i in d.keys(): # in this case i is the docID
          DF1 = DF1+1 # counter to get the document frequency of a term
          print i

  print "document frequency of wordQ1 is",DF1 # document frequency
  ```

  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is FinalHash?  It looks like a class, not a valid dictionary.  Is this the full working example?  It's hard to provide feedback without more context.

Comment: Is that a data structure you're building yourself? Because making a list of one-element dictionaries is usually pretty silly (you should combine them all into the same dictionary instead).

Comment: Final Hash is a default dictionary not a class

Comment: FinalHash is an inverted index of terms and documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the values in your inner dictionaries by changing how you loop on them. Replace the `for i in d.keys()` loop with something like this:

```
for DocID, (TF, DocSize) in d.items():
    # ...
```

You haven't actually explained what you want to do with the `TF` and `DocSize` values, so I've left the actual contents of the loop up to you.

Note that needing a loop here is a bit silly. If you are the one creating the data structure you're working on (rather than getting it from some external source), you should probably change its design to be a single dictionary (at this level) rather than a list of dictionaries, each with a single key. That is, you'd get rid of the `Term_List1` level of the data structure, and get `d` directly at that point.